Custom user storage provider via Keycloak SPI - Assistance troubleshooting
thanks in advance!
Steps taken:
I have created the below project, "KeycloakRemoteUserStorageProvider", which uses the Keycloak SPI to define a custom UserModel, and, to verify user credentials, it sends HTTP requests to a remote Spring Boot microservice ("RemoteUserWebService") which connects to a MYSQL database.
"KeycloakUserStorageProvider": https://github.com/kscull/KeycloakRemoteUserStorageProvider/tree/main
"RemoteUserWebService": https://github.com/kscull/RemoteUserWebService/tree/main
For deployment, I packaged my "KeycloakRemoteUserStorageProvider" into a JAR and pasted the JAR into the "providers" directory of Keycloak. I then ran the below command which executed successfully:
kc.sh build

I started up and logged into Keycloak as admin, created a Realm, Client, and added my user federation within the desired realm, and yes, the custom federation appeared after adding the JAR.
Next, I sent an HTTP GET request to get an authorization code, to the below URL (Keycloak running on port 8080:
http://localhost:8080/realms/appsdeveloperblog/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=photo-app-code-flow-client&response_type=code&scope=openid&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/callback&state=asfwerwsdfwejj
I'm then presented with Keycloak's login screen, and I provide an email and password which are within my custom MYSQL database (email="test@gmail.com" and password of "test" which you can see is created upon startup of the RemoteUserWebService) , and my "RemoteUserWebService" does receive the HTTP request from my "KeycloakRemoteUserStorageProvider" and even prints that the provided password matches.
Desired Result:
However, the desired result at this point would be that Keycloak redirects to the provided redirect_uri query param, but, instead, I am presented with the below page, prompting me to update my account information, but with no error at all in the console running Keycloak. In fact, when I do a log to the console in my KeycloakRemoteUserStorageProvider, I print the value of the returned UserModel and it indeed shows the ID which is in my remote database, proving that the user was loaded by the remoteUserWebService successfully, and a UserModel was created with at least the ID field being populated correctly:

I've followed documentation and looked towards some example code elsewhere as well, and I'm not sure what the issue is, though I assume it has something to do with improper population of fields in my custom AbstractUserAdapter class ("UserAdapter").
Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks so much

Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it? - Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?

You could look further than the links I pasted and realize that I provided an outline of the relevant steps taken in the context of deployment? Or not...

Questions shouldn't relay on external sources to be comprehensible

@Keith did you managed to find the solution for this?
